# Why is initramfs dropping to a shell after installing Ubuntu next to a Windows 10 installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, prompt

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via Live USB on an ASUS Zenbook 13 UX331UN that is shipped with a preinstalled Windows 10. It is a UEFI system with secure boot enabled and fast boot disabled. I'm sitting here for days now trying to get Ubuntu to boot but to no avail.

`fdisk -lu` gives me the following partition layout

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 94F7C923-6092-46D5-AFD6-38F3F4F6096F

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296  946147327 945580032 450.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  998576128 1000214527   1638400   800M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  946147328  998576127  52428800    25G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

The file `boot/grub/grub.cfg` created by the Ubuntu installer contains the following menu entry to boot Ubuntu

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-97209f84-060d-4e49-a790-e9af75f2dc40' {
    ...
    set root='hd0,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  97209f84-060d-4e49-a790-e9af75f2dc40
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 97209f84-060d-4e49-a790-e9af75f2dc40
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/sda5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
}
```

but it results in

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/97209f84-060d-4e49-a790-e9af75f2dc40 does not exist. Dropping to a shell
initramfs:_
```

I've tried numerous possible fixes including reinstalling grub, boot-repair, manually altering EFI but ... nothing.

As last resort, I tried booting Ubuntu from the grub prompt manually as described in many tutorials out there with the following commands

```
set root=(hd0,5)
linux   /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro
initrd  /initrd.img
boot
```

and ... tada, it boots successfully.

Then I adopted these commands into grub.cfg and now the menu entry look like this

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-97209f84-060d-4e49-a790-e9af75f2dc40' {
    ...
    set root=(hd0,5)
    linux   /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro quiet splash
    initrd  /initrd.img
}
```

With this entry configuration, Ubuntu boots successfully.

Is it a valid approach to change the `grub.cfg` in that way? Do I have to face possible side effects by these changes and why can't Ubuntu create a working `grub.cfg` itself?

**Update 1**

I think I found the culprit.

Firstly, the `UUID` is wrong, as already pointed out by Gilles, hence I reverted to the original `grub.cfg` and changed all occurrences of `97209f84-` to `44ada74f-`. But still with this change, it's not booting, as I still get a *dropping to a shell* prompt. To verify a `UUID` issue, I reinstalled Ubuntu, now the `UUID` is a different one (as it gets generated when a partition is formatted as far as I know) but now grub.cfg states the correct `UUID` of `/dev/sda5`. Very strange. So the `UUID` is clearly not the issue.

Secondly, I replaced `set root='hd0,gpt5'` with `set root=(hd0,5)` but that doesn't seem to make a difference either. On the third attempt, I changed the filename in the `linux` command from `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic.efi.signed` to `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic` and ... now it boots.

After successfully verifying the existance of  file `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic.efi.signed` I now think that the system does not trust it according to the answer of this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/883814/678215

Any ideas why `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic.efi.signed` is not working?

Comment: @Fabby Exactly my thoughts while checking the partition layout in the Ubuntu installer the first time. I knew it would probably cause issues as no tutorial ever showcased such a layout ...thank you, i will try to test this when i have some spare time.

Comment: @Fabby The order of partition starting offsets and the order of partition numbers doesn't have to match. It's less confusing for humans if they do, but the computer doesn't care.

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable than me has a different opinion. @Gilles Can you drop by /dev/chat? **ViRuSTriNiTy** could you post `parted --list` instead of `fdisk -l`???

Comment: @Gilles Yes, sure, the numbers match the partition chart shown to me while installing Ubuntu. The partition chart looked like this: `EFI | Reserved | Windows | Unpartitioned space | Recovery` and then the installer took the unpartitioned space and added partition 5 (`/dev/sda5`) before partition 4.

Comment: can you also add the contents of fstab on top of `parted --list`? or drop by in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat)

Comment: Use `lsblk -f` to get the UUID of your root partition and use that instead of /dev/sda5. It's better in the long term, especially if you add more drives later, since /dev/sdXY gets ordered by what the kernel finds first on each boot.

Comment: Note that `grub.cfg` is generated by `update-grub`, which runs on every update of the kernel or Grub. Your manual modifications will be lost when that happens. I don't know where it's pulling that UUID from. It doesn't make sense to me: that's the UUID of the _disk_, not the UUID of the root partition.

Comment: @Gilles not quite: disk: `94F7C923...` ; grub root call: `97209f84...`, but we won't really know root's UUID until OP posts the full partition info with all UUIDs...

Comment: @Mioriin Oh! Thank you! I managed to repeatedly misread this. OP posted some extra information in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44559181#44559181) but nothing has that `9720…` UUID. Weird. ViRuSTriNiTy, it should work with `44ada74f-dab5-4ac9-ba79-3ed080ff425b` (the UUID of the root filesystem).